# my tablet requires a pass code in order to turn it off but I dont have my my code

Tags: samsung

My tablet requires my password to be turned off but I forgot my password and I already tried google's suggestion. Is there another method for retoring my device?

Answer (score 0):

Do the Hard Reset.

Depending on your phone/tablet, boot into recovery but usually this is how it is:

- Since you tablet doesn't turn off. Press power button + Volume Down till it powers off. This is a feature of some tablets.
- Press Power off + Volume Up to boot into recovery.
- Perform wipe cache partition
- Then wipe data/factory reset
- Reboot.

Comment: Be aware that this will likely trigger FRP and the current Google Account credentials will be required to get back into the device.